# Countdown is starting anew if I reload the page - how to set fix

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have downloaded a free coundown coming soon page, but the problem is that If I reload the page, the countdown is starting anew. this is the script:

http://pastebin.com/mHz5EF2y

how can I make it start once and keep counting even during reloading the page?

Comment: javascript can only time from the start of a page refresh - you need to start the timer with an ajax type call to your server

Comment: Or store the time the page loaded in localStorage, and see if there is already a time set in localStorage to base the countdown off of on page load.

Comment: @dave, how can i do this?

Comment: do you want it to countdown to a certain date so that is shows the time until a certain date?

Comment: @Markasoftware YES! :)

Comment: looks like somebody else already answered :)

Comment: If you're counting down to a specific date, you shouldn't have any problems. Calculate the remaining time on page load, then update your counter every second or so (`setInterval` or `setTimeout` would work well). You may want to periodically recalculate the time remaining as I don't think either of those methods are completely precise. There's no need to "remember" the time remaining between page loads since it's trivial to compute.

Comment: @Mark He isn't coding the countdown. That's already prebuilt. You are right about the setInterval and setTimeout though. They will get off track after a while. setTimeout is really bad for timers because it takes some time to execute the setTimeout and all the other code between every tick. So instead of a ticking every 1000ms it ticks every 1000ms + ##ms to execute all code in the loop. It is never exactly 1000ms between ticks.

Comment: @DutGRIFF: Losing a few ms here and there on a 15 day count isn't a big deal :-) If we lose 2ms a pop (1 second), it will take over 8 minutes to be off by a full second. Anyway.. looks like you got this covered!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Client side javascript (javascript running in the browser) will not update the server. This isn't how javascript works. Your javascript is sent to the client and run in their browser so you can not make changes to the server without ajax or some kind of communication with the server.

It seems like you are expecting to launch your site in 15 days. There are a few options here but if you are just wanting to countdown to a certain date and time then the easiest is just to use the javascript Date function to generate the timestamp of that date and time then subtract the timestamp of the current date and time. This will give you the millisecond until this time. Use this number in your countdown.

If you are trying to count down to December 1st 2013 at 8pm you can do it like this:

```
var endTime = new Date(2013, 11, 1, 20).getTime();
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var timeLeft = endTime - startTime;
$('#counter').countdown({
  timestamp : timeLeft
});
```

Comment: Not that I can see. I ran the code in the console for Google Chrome and I get this exactly what I want. Are you getting any errors? Do you know how to use Console for Safari/Chrome or Firebug for Firefox? These really make programming in Javascript a breeze. If you can check the console I may be able to tell you what is wrong.

Comment: console is empty, no errors. kinda weird... do you get counter running or just the wanted time?